# Parsing query string inside fragment with Elm

Tags: elm, url-parsing

For [reasons](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/479#issuecomment-365679015) I need to parse something which looks is formatted as a query string (i.e. `key=value&another_key=another_value`), but which is in the fragment of a URL, e.g:

http://example.com/callback#id_token=my_long_jwt&state=some_state

If the `#` was a `?`, then it would be easy using [`<?>`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/url/latest/Url-Parser#(%3C?%3E)), but I can't figure out how (or if) I can use `Url.Parser.Query` when it's in a fragment.

---

I can get the fragment as a `String`:

```
import Url.Parser as Parser
import Url.Parser exposing ((</>))

type Route = Callback String | NotFound

route : Parser.Parser (Route -> a) a
route = Parser.map Callback (Parser.s "callback" </> fragmentWithDefault )

fragmentWithDefault : Parser.Parser (String -> a) a
fragmentWithDefault = Parser.fragment <| Maybe.withDefault "no_fragment"

toRoute : Url.Url -> Route
toRoute url = Maybe.withDefault NotFound (Url.Parser.parse route url)
```

But there is no API in [`Url.Parser.Query`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/url/latest/Url-Parser-Query) which runs a `Url.Parser.Query.Parser` against which I can run the `String` in `Callback`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Url parser just treats Url fragment as a `String` but you can replace `#` with `?` before parsing:

```
Maybe.withDefault url <| Url.fromString <| String.replace '#' '?' <| Url.toString url
```

then you will get your fragment in query part so you can parse it normally.